# How do I declare the lifetime parameters for a type which contains a reference to a type with a lifetime parameter?

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker

Trying to figure out how to describe this lifetime relationship.

So let's say I have a component which has a lifetime parameter:

```
struct Foo<'a> { ... }
```

And let's say I want to have another component which contains a reference to `Foo`

```
struct Bar<??> {
    foo: &'? Foo<'?>
}
```

How do I express the following:

1. The lifetime of the reference to `foo` should be the lifetime of the `Bar` containing it
2. I don't care about the lifetime of the underlying `Foo`, so long as it's longer than the lifetime of the `Bar` containing the reference

**edit**: So if `Foo` itself didn't have a lifetime parameter, I would implement `Bar` like this:

```
struct Bar<'a> {
    foo: &'a Foo
}
```

But I don't know how to handle the parameter on `Foo`.

Comment: What do you mean by "The lifetime of the reference to `foo` should be the lifetime of the `Bar` containing it"? Do you want to create a `Foo` that contains a `Bar` that contains the same `Foo`?

Comment: You can use `&'a Foo<'a>`.

Comment: No what I mean is, the reference `bar.foo` should only live as long as `bar`, but the actual `Foo` instance: `*bar.foo` can live longer than `bar`.

I edited the question, maybe it's a bit more clear.

Comment: The reference will always live as long as `bar` because it is a member of `Bar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't care about the lifetime of the underlying Foo, so long as it's longer than the lifetime of the Bar containing the reference

First, the lifetime can be read like "this element lives at least 'x", so when you declaring  `struct Foo<'a> { ... }` means a X instance of Foo lives at least 'a, where 'a is a variable like any other variable, but is a lifetime variable.

Now,

> How do I express the following:
> The lifetime of the reference to foo should be the lifetime of the Bar containing it

To express this you need declare the lifetime variable for `Bar` and pass it to `Foo` like this

```rust
struct Bar<'a> {
    foo: &'a Foo<'a>
}
```

or

```rust
struct Bar<'a> {
    foo: Foo<'a>
}
```

The difference between one and the other is semantic, and means that one contains an element of type `Foo<'a>` and the other contains a reference to an element of type `Foo<'a>`.

Now,

> I don't care about the lifetime of the underlying Foo, so long as it's longer than the lifetime of the Bar containing the reference

Passing a lifetime 'down' necessarily implies that the children element lives at least as long as its parent, but not necessarily that it lives longer. To express that regardless of the parent's lifetime the child lives in a major scope you would need to use a 'static' lifetime. Like this

```rust
struct Bar {
    foo: &'static Foo<'static>
}
```

or

```rust
struct Bar {
    foo: Foo<'static>
}
```

also you can make some like this

```rust
struct Bar<'a> {
    foo: &'a Foo<'static>
}
```

which means that the reference to the element lives as long as the parent but the element itself has a wider scope

I don't know if this answers your question, I hope it helps

Comment: " To express that regardless of the parent's lifetime the child lives in a major scope you would need to use a 'static' lifetime" - that's not fully correct. Almost always in such cases `'static` lifetime will be much stricter then necessary.

Comment: yes indeed! `'static` implies that the object can live much longer than it needs to, but you couldn't declare a child element with a longer lifetime than the parent by eluding the lifetime declaration on the parent element without a `'static`